# What happened to the Republic equipment after the Clone Wars?

Tags: star-wars

During the Clone Wars, the clones utilized various armors, weapons, and vehicles. I am aware that the Empire continued to use some, and I'm also aware that some fell into the hands of the rebellion. But what did the Empire do with the rest of the equipment. Did they sell it, attempt to destroy it, or get rid of it in some other form?

Comment: What does anyone do with war equipment that's no longer needed? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_surplus

Comment: @Valorum - if they are anything like the British... they would have sold it to  someone from the commonwealth or Saudi Arabia

Comment: Possibly sold to Hutts..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Empire did continue to use some Republic vehicles, such as the [HAVw A6 Juggernaut](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/HAVw_A6_Juggernaut), the [74-Z speeder bike](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/74-Z_speeder_bike) and various Star Destroyers.

Other Republic vehicles ended up in the hands of the Rebel Alliance, such as the [AT-AP Walker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/AT-AP_Walker) and [the All Terrain Tactical Enforcer](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/All_Terrain_Tactical_Enforcer).

The [All Terrain Recon Transport](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/All_Terrain_Recon_Transport) was used by both the Empire and the Rebellion.

Other vehicles were simply abandoned, as seen within the ruined [Fort Anaxes](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fort_Anaxes).

[image]

This practice is likely what allowed to [Old Jho's Pit Stop](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Old_Jho%27s_Pit_Stop?file=Old_Jho_Pit_Stop.jpg) to acquire the remains of an old gunship.

[image]

It's unknown what the Empire did with the rest of its excess equipment. It was likely scrapped or destroyed, in order to keep it out of the hands of Rebels and criminals.

Comment: I would like to see if there is anymore information you have, but I will still accept this answer.

Comment: @donatello If I come across anything new, I'll definitely update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After the fall of the republic, the empire continued to use republic vehicles till they were phased out by new imperial technology. After they were replaced, many of these vehicles were sent to planets that were just massive scrap yards, where millions of workers would tear apart the materials from these old ships, and use them for newer imperial ships.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The accepted answer mentions this for certain vehicles, and gives examples of other possibilities.  Do you have any specific cases you can add?